# Write to Excel Spreadsheet

Tags: python, python-2.7, openpyxl

I am new to Python. I need to write some data from my program to a spreadsheet. I am using openpyxl package. (Some suggest to write to a csv file (never used csv & don't really understand what it is).

The program is very simple. I have 2 columns, compare there values and write the common value in Excel Sheet.

```
import openpyxl        

wb=openpyxl.load_workbook('activities.xlsx')     # open file

assign_sheet=wb.active

for i in range(3, 8):

   cell_1 = assign_sheet.cell(row=i, column=2).value
   cell_2 =assign_sheet.cell(row=i, column=3).value
   s1= cell_1.split(" ")
   s2= cell_2.split(" ")
   temp=[]
  for w in s1:
    if w in s2:
        temp.append(w)
        from openpyxl import Workbook
        ws1 = wb.get_sheet_by_name("Sheet1")
        for i in range(3, 8):
        ws1.cell(row=i, column=5).value=temp[0]
        wb.save("activities.xlsx")
```

It gets the job done except the last part (writing in the excel sheet & and i am reading and writing in the same file).

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: i want to add my data in excel sheet

Answer (score 0):

There should be a indentation after the for loop

```
for i in range(3, 8):
    ws1.cell(row=i, column=5).value=temp[0]
    wb.save("activities.xlsx")
```

Comment: but this save nothing in the excel sheet

Comment: write a print statement and check whether you are getting any values for temp[0]

Comment: In this line ws1.cell(row=i, column=5).value=temp[0] replace temp[0] with a string/integer and check whether that value is saved into the cell.

Comment: because you are overwriting the value in the same cell ws1.cell(row=i, column=5) inside your for loop

Comment: i have change this now only one value is store in all cells, either i use temp[0], temp (on temp[1] give me an error)